# So I implemented logins in Django but how do I make it "stay logged in"?

Tags: python, django, authentication

So I implemented the authentication backend into my Django website, but it seems after I login successfully, it doesn't seem to stay that way. Or in other words how do I make it so I can't access the website without logging in successfully and when I do login it stays that way until i logout?

Answer (score 0):

In the main URLCONF for your site, you should have something similar to the following lines (if you are using the default authentication system):

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',{'next_page': '/login/'}),
```

With that in place, you can define which pages/views on your site require the user to be logged in (here done in `myapp/urls.py`):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   # e.g. /myapp/                                                                                            
                   url(r'^$', login_required(views.some_view())),)
```

The `login_required` decorator forces Django to check authentication before returning a view.

Comment: It still goes straight to the page. If my registration app is separate from the app with the view I want to control for logins will it still work if I edit the `urls.py` in that other app the way you showed me?

Comment: Yes, the registration app can be completely separate from the app you want to place login restrictions on, as long as it is available from with in the same project and is registered in the INSTALLED_APPS